# can i go to malaysia from singapore and then go back to singapore in the same day?

Tags: singapore, malaysia

i book a one way cruise from singapore to malaysia, and i planned to take a bus from KL in the same day (at night preferably) back to singapore. is it possible to do so?

Comment: It will be tight to do all that in one day. Cruise from Singapore to (I presume) Port Klang is 5 hours, then Port Klang to KL is 1.5 hours, then bus from KL to Singapore is (at least) 5 hours depending on traffic.

Comment: @user24096 Cruises from SG to Malaysia are typically overnight or longer.  All they want to do in one day is the ship-MY-SG bit.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, there is no requirement to stay overnight.  You can just write "TRANSIT" for your address in the entry form.

This of course assumes you have a valid visa or visa-free status for Malaysia, and it may be helpful to prebook your bus ticket out of Malaysia, so you can show it if asked.